# Do durable events in MassTransit ever expire?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm positive I'm missing a nuance of MassTranist and/or RabbitMQ, but how long do durable (permanent?) messages stay on queues?

The situation I'm thinking of is one in which all consumers of a certain type of event are unavailable - obviously when they come back up, you want them to be able to take the appropriate actions based on the events they "missed" while they were offline.

However, what about the case when a new consumer starts reading off of the same queue after days/months/years?  Is that consumer now going to be pulling in all events since the beginning of time?  I'm almost certain that's not the case, but how is durability balanced with timeliness?

Answer (score 0):

As I know MassTransit doesn't control message lifetime. RabbitMQ doing the same, thus message will stay in queue forever. The only exception from this is request/response model in which you can set up timeout period in which you want accept response.
In common way if you need to control lifetime you can store creating time in the message and check it in consumers.

Comment: You can set a message time to live, by default with MassTransit, it's a really long time (at least a year).

Comment: What happens when the time to live expires. Does the message disappear or fault?